# Multiple repeated elements between text

Tags: regex

I was wondering how it's possible (if it is) to get multiple elements between text.

For example my test String is `<pizza>name:1;John:2</pizza>Carl:8`and I want to get all the `Names:number` that are **between** the `<pizza>` tags.

If I use `\w+:\d` I get `name:1`, `John:2` **but also** `Carl:8`.

Is there a way to get only the ones inside the  tags? (So only `name:1` and `John:2` in this case)

I've tried using `<pizza>(\w+:\d;)+</pizza>` but it only gives me the last one that's inside.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
(?<=<pizza>).*?(?=</pizza>)
```

Positive lookbehind

```
(?<=<pizza>)
```

Matches the actual value you want to extract

```
.*?
```

Positive lookahead

```
(?=</pizza>)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works ! I did not know things such as lookbehinds and lookaheads existed.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: Oh thanks :D
I was actually searching a tutorial about this.